# Python: function parameter between quotations for columns

Tags: python, function

Basically I need the following:

```
data['sales']*10
data['height']*10
```

The underlying problem I am facing is how can I create a function where I can write the variable names without 
adding the quotations inside the function.
Is this possible? For example, like writing a special character inside the " " that indicates a word is an argument.

```
def function(var1):
   p=data['var1']*10  #The error is here; I tried p=data["'"+var1+"'"]*10
                    #Is there a way to indicate var1 is not a string,
                    #like p=data['&var1']*10
return p

function(sales)
function(height)
```

I know the question is very basic, but I need to know if it is possible. If not, i will just create all functions and add the quotations for each argument.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to pass the strings (field/column name) to your function as an argument which will be stored into the variable `var1`. You then don't need to put the quotes around `var1` inside your function. For example, do the following

```
def function(var1):
   p=data[var1]*10  #The error is here; I tried p=data["'"+var1+"'"]*10
                    #Is there a way to indicate var1 is not a string,
                    #like p=data['&var1']*10
   return p

function('sales')
function('height')
```